# Download artifact contents from another pipeline build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have two azure devops pipelines as follows:

- the first one creates an artifact under the name 'AncientArtifact-1.2.0.$(Build.BuildId)'.
- the second one is trying to use this artifact using the [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task configured as follows:
  [image]

This creates a folder named 'AncientArtifact-1.2.0.12345' (first pipeline most recent BuildId=12345) inside a $(CustomDestinationFolder) in the second pipeline build.

I want to rename the above folder to something like 'ancient' and move it to another directory within the second pipeline build to be included in the second pipeline artifact.

I have tried using the [copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task but the problem is I don't know the name of the downloaded artifact folder thus I can only specify its parent $(CustomDestinationFolder) as source folder and so my destination folder will look something like $(destinationFolder)\AncientArtifact-1.2.0.12345*.
Using the flattenFolders option will flatten everything and that is not what I want.

Some approaches come to mind:

- Remove the $(Build.BuildId) from the artifact name. This way I know the exact name that the downloaded artifact will have. The issue is that I would like to keep it.
- A custom script in the second pipeline that would list the folders inside the $(CustomDestinationFolder), get the name of the artifact folder rename it a hardcoded 'ancient' name. It feels quite hackish.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: May I know how's the status of this? What about below work around? Free to share what is your puzzle the question you still having:-)

Comment: Hi @Alexandru, Can you please add code fragment for setting up the reference name of the DownloadBuildArtifacts. I've read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts) and the [code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/5e5cd15cd9/Tasks/DownloadBuildArtifactsV0/main.ts) but I was not able to find the relevant section. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different with Eric, here I just follow your **idea1** by keeping `$(Build.buildId)` specified in artifact name.

If you set the `system.debug` of `pipeline2` as `true`, you will see that the task `DownloadBuildArtifacts` itself generate one environment variable based on different builds used: `BuildNumber`

[image]

Just make use of it, set `reference name` of `DownloadBuildArtifacts` task: `ref`.

Then, you can call this variable to get `buildid` value during next steps: `$(ref.BuildNumber)`.

Meanwhile, you can use **copy files** task by keeping the artifact name contain the `$(Build.BuildId)` value in it.

Comment: Hi @Merlin Liang - Can you please add code fragment for setting up the reference name of the DownloadBuildArtifacts. I've read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts) and the [code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/5e5cd15cd9/Tasks/DownloadBuildArtifactsV0/main.ts) but I was not able to find the relevant section. Thanks.

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha Please scroll down the download build artifact task configuration page, and you will see **Output Variables**. Click that, then you should be able to define your reference name in the blank. Since this is a general parameter that exists on all pipeline tasks, we do not mentioned these on all tasks' documentation. We just document it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks

Comment: Merlin Liang - Thanks for the help! I had created a Github Issue for this question and I've added the answer there. Here is the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13720#issuecomment-710104698).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do go down a route with the copy file task and wildcards to get what you want.

But if you ultimately want to rename the artifact folder for inclusion in the second pipeline, I would just go ahead rename the artifact folder after you download it.

I would not call it hackish, if it solves the problem simply and is easy to understand.

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'your-project'
    pipeline: 'your-pipeline'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    downloadType: 'specific'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\customLocation'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: Get-ChildItem $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\customLocation | Rename-Item -NewName 'ancient'
```